# Angular material 2 autocomplete position wrong

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a problem with autocomplete of material 2.

In my case, I populate the list when the user write down something in the input, but the div(panel) with the options always appear  bellow (If the screen is small I have to scroll down the page). It should appear above the input field when screen is small.

I think the problem is that the position of the panel is only initialised at the beginning when the input is clicked. Anyone can help me with any solution? Is there a way to reset positionY when the list is updated?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make it easier to understand and help, please see the **how to ask** https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem was core css classes missing from the project.

[Fix] in style.css, at top level, add:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to add this to your style.css

```
.cdk-overlay-container{position:fixed;z-index:1000}
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper{display:flex;position:absolute;z-index:1000}
.cdk-overlay-pane{position:absolute;pointer-events:auto;box-sizing:border-
 box;z-index:1000}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't solve my problem, I already had this properties included in my css, except the class .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper which i can't find. But i added the 3 and it's still working in the same way.Anyway, thanks for try it.

Comment: got it positioned correctly after adding ::ng-deep  to each style. But now cdk-overlay-container is not removed after an item select :/

Comment: I come back and say it is partial fix only.